# Procedure of a recursive function

Tags: python, recursion

I came across this code that traces the flow of a recursive function

```
def summation(lower, upper, margin):                              (1)
    blanks = " " * margin                                         (2)
    print(blanks, lower, upper)                                   (3)
    if lower > upper:                                             (5)
        print(blanks, 0)                                          (6)
        return 0                                                  
    else:
        result = lower + summation(lower + 1, upper, margin + 4)  (4)
        print('*', blanks, result)                                (7)                 
        return result
```

However, I can't understand the flow of the **second half of the output** in the example below

```
summation(1, 4, 0)

# Output:
1 4                    (from step 3)
     2 4               (from step 3)
         3 4           (from step 3)
             4 4       (from step 3)
                 5 4   (from step 3)
                 0
             4 <=== How could the function "know" to calculate the `blanks` and the `result`?
         7 <=== ???
     9 <=== ???
 10 <=== ???
10
```

From my understanding the code was executed from step (1) to step (6), but how could it know to execute step(7) *repeatedly* with *correct* values of `result` and `blanks`?

Could someone please explain to me as plainly/clearly as possible?

Thanks.

Comment: It will execute 1,2,3,4 repeatedly, pushing all variables to the stack each time. When You reach (6) or (8) it will pop the stack frame then execute the remaining part of (4) and (7). It knows what values it needs to use because they will be stored on each stack frame

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack

Comment: Maybe you didn't realise that every execution of the `summation` function has its **own** set of local variables, despite they happen to have the same names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Realise that each execution of `summation` *has its own set of variables*. So every execution has its own `lower`, `upper`, `margin`, `blanks` and `result`. They don't interfere with eachother.

Maybe it helps to append *accents* to those names (indicating to which execution context they belong). Then the initial call of `summation(1, 4, 0)` has:

```
lower: 1
upper: 4
margin: 0
blanks: ""
```

The recursive call will see this:

```
lower´: 2
upper´: 4
margin´: 4
blanks´: "    "
```

And so we can go deeper in the recursive executions, but eventually recursion will unwind, and each execution context will resume with its own variables.

If we represent every execution context of the function as a separate column in a table (identified by a recursion depth going from 0 to n), we could visualise it like this:

| name | depth 0 | depth 1 | depth 2 | depth 3 | depth 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `lower` | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| `upper` | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 4 |
| `margin` | 0 | 4 | 8 | 12 | 16 |
| `blanks` | `""` | `" "` | `" "` | `" "` | `" "` |

When at the deepest level of recursion, all these values are in memory, and when the deepest function execution executes a `return`, we can imagine the rightmost column is removed from the table. But the remaining columns are still there, with values that have not been altered from what they were. These columns are *stack frames* in reality that live on the *call stack*.

Comment: Wow, this is beautiful! Thank you for an intelligent explanation. I didn't realise that each summation has *its own set of variables*. The enlightening point was the *stack frames that live on the call stack* which explains why the function *knew* how to repeatedly print out the relevant information. Without your answer, I don't think I could understand how the code produced such output. Interestingly, this example came from the book *Fundamental of Python* and the author didn't bother to explain the mechanism/behind the scene of the code.

Answer (score 2):

The blanks are computed for each depth of recursion, if you change a bit the code to track the depth level (quick edit, up to a depth level of 9):

```
def summation(lower, upper, margin, depth=0):                            
    blanks = "-" * margin                                       
    print(depth, blanks, lower, upper)                                 
    if lower > upper:                                           
        print(depth, blanks, 0)                                        
        return 0                                                  
    else:
        result = lower + summation(lower + 1, upper, margin + 4, depth=depth+1)
        print(depth, '*', blanks, result)                                              
        return result
```

You can see that the blanks are remaining the same within a depth level as the variables have their own scope.

`result` is updated in `result = lower + summation(lower + 1, upper, margin + 4)`

`print` output:

```
0  1 4
1 ---- 2 4
2 -------- 3 4
3 ------------ 4 4
4 ---------------- 5 4
4 ---------------- 0
3 * ------------ 4
2 * -------- 7
1 * ---- 9
0 *  10
```

Answer (score -2):

```
1 4 
|   2 4 
|   |   3 4 
|   |   |   4 4
|   |   |   |  5 4 #-> 5 > Higher than 4
|   |   |   |  0
|   |   |   |  |
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 +0
|   |   |   |
10  9   7   4
```

Comment: Some explanation would greatly improve this answer.